# How to properly Redirect To Page in Blazor server side?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Simple doubt here...

in asp.net core MCV controller I could redirect to some pages using RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller") from server side.

Is there any way to do it using Blazor Server Side?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In blazor server side, you could redirect to page by using `NavigationManager`:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavManager


<p>Redirecting to Page</p>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/fetchdata");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway to do it from API side?

Comment: Hi @H.Eberhardt, Did you mean you want to redirect to razor component in controller?

Comment: Hi, @Rena, yes that will be useful and even to an external domain with a redirect response. Thanks in advance!