# In Blazor (server) how can I redirect a request

Tags: blazor, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

This is a follow-on to [RegisterConfirmation failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76096949/registerconfirmation-failing).

The ASP.NET Core Identity scaffold has the following on missing parameters in a ton of their .cshtml.cs files:

```
if (someParam == null)
   {
       return RedirectToPage("/Index");
   }
```

Which displays:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: No page named '/Index' matches the supplied values.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectToPageResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, RedirectToPageResult result)
```

I prefer not to have to instantiate the 25+ files to go change that RedirectToPage() call. So, is there a way in Blazor I can tell it that when it receives a request to "/Index", display "/" (the default root page)?

```
app.MapGet("/Index", () => Results.Redirect("/_Host"));
```

But still get the error. Also weird, if I go to the browser and put in `https://localhost:7229/Identity/Account/ConfirmEmail`, that displays fine. So there's something about a MVC module redirecting in a Blazor app that is causing this problem.

Comment: David, `app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");` in `Program's` HttpRequest pipeline should already handle that.  It's the default server side route that points to the Blazor startup page.  What does your Program request pipeline setup look like? Try adding a simple `Index.cshtml` and seeing if it lands there.  Did you add Identity later, or as part of the solution creation?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yep tried that. Going to Index then said it had a conflict between Index.cshtml and _Host.cshtml. This is all very weird and I think it's due to the Identity pages being MVC in a Blazor app. I think I'm going to instantiate the Identity code and change how it redirects.

Comment: See my answer on how I reproduced and got the redirect working.

Comment: The answer here is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67102853/22019322

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your problem by scaffolding the `Login` page and then changing this section:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    //...
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //...
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            //return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
    //...
}
```

So I added an `Index.cshtml` to `Pages` and set the `@Page` directive

```cs
@page "/Index"
@model SO76112180.Pages.IndexModel
<div>Hello</div>
```

At this point I landed on this page.

I then added:

```cs
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return LocalRedirect("/");
        }
    }
```

which redirected me back to the Blazor SPA.

Answer (score 0):

If u want the caller to be able to navigate to your root page when the caller rqeuests '/index' you can declare two page directives '/index' and '/' for the page.

```
@page "/"
@page "/index"


<h1>Hello from root</h1>

@code
{
   
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the call to RedirectToPage() is not in my code. So I can't change it.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missunderstood the question. I have updated the answer. Hopefully this will suit your needs.

Comment: I tried that. It conflicts with _Host.cshtml. This is a very weird issue that I think is due to the Identity modules being MVC interacting with a Blazor app.

Answer (score 0):

David, I think in this case you might want to consider using Middleware, which gets called before the request ever gets to the Blazor engine.  This will give you a really high-level control over a lot of client-server traffic.  You can check if there's already an identity user, you can rewrite the URL, or you can just serve any arbitrary page you want.

It's a bit daunting at first, but even if you can solve your current problem without MiddleWare, this would be a great opportunity to learn about it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/middleware

And here's the module I think you're probably looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: I tried that - same error. This is all very weird and I think it's due to the Identity pages being MVC in a Blazor app. I think I'm going to instantiate the Identity code and change how it redirects.

Comment: tbh, you might just be hitting yourself for no good reason  Why not just make an Index page?